# Enabling `flyspell-prog-mode` starts `flyspell-mode` instead

Tags: flyspell, ispell

I've been playing with `flyspell` lately and with my recently established setup for spell-check, I wanted to enable it for all modes. I found that `flyspell-mode` and `flyspell-prog-mode` are best for `text-mode` and `prog-mode` respectively and found in an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20078310/1749585) that it can be done as:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          'flyspell-prog-mode)
```

I've done the same thing but have noticed that for both the cases, `flyspell-mode` gets enabled and the `flyspell-prog-mode` doesn't get enabled at all. My code can be found [here](https://github.com/myTerminal/.emacs.d/blob/2cead62c7bf197f6cef1859a95247657e5a0e8b3/.emacs.d/myTerminal/config-misc.el#L67) and it's the exact same as suggested.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To help answer this question, we can perform the following steps:

1. Load the `flyspell.el` library by typing `M:` aka `M-x eval-expression`, and then `(require 'flyspell)`
2. Locate the source code for the function `flyspell-prog-mode` by typing:

   `M-x find-function RET flyspell-prog-mode RET`

Step two leads us to the source code of the function `flyspell-prog-mode`, which looks like this in Emacs 26:

```lisp
(defun flyspell-prog-mode ()
  "Turn on `flyspell-mode' for comments and strings."
  (interactive)
  (setq flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate
        #'flyspell-generic-progmode-verify)
  (setq-local flyspell--prev-meta-tab-binding
              (or (local-key-binding "\M-\t" t)
                  (global-key-binding "\M-\t" t)))
  (flyspell-mode 1)
  (run-hooks 'flyspell-prog-mode-hook))
```

Based upon our review of the source code, we now know that `flsypell-mode` is activated when calling `flyspell-prog-mode`, which is the second to the last line that reads:  `(flyspell-mode 1)`.  And, we see that two variables are expressly set when calling `flyspell-prog-mode`; i.e., `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` and `flyspell--prev-meta-tab-binding`.  We observe that `flyspell--prev-meta-tab-binding` is set on a buffer-local basis with `setq-local`.

We see that `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` is set with `setq` and we wonder to ourselves whether that variable is buffer-local already or whether the value is being modified on a global basis.  To satisfy our curiosity, we look up the variable with `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable`.  We read the `*Help*` buffer and see that this variable was already buffer-local and we surmise that this is the reason why `setq` was used when setting the aforementioned variable in the function `flyspell-prog-mode` -- the `*Help*` buffer states in relevant part: "*Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.*"

**CONCLUSION**:  `flyspell-prog-mode` is not really a mode *per se*; i.e., it is not a minor-mode and it is not a major-mode.  Instead, it is just `flyspell-mode` *plus* the setting of two variables on a buffer-local basis; i.e., `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` and `flyspell--prev-meta-tab-binding`.  `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` is set with the value of a *function* named `flyspell-generic-progmode-verify`.  `flyspell--prev-meta-tab-binding` is a keyboard shortcut.  The hook `flyspell-prog-mode-hook` has no default value, but we could add anything that is appropriate; e.g., `(add-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode-hook (lambda () (message "Turned on flyspell-prog-mode ...")))`

Comment: I had a suspicion but that shows the proof! However, as per the description, `flyspell-prog-mode` is supposed to only run spell-check on comments and strings in a program buffer, but I see that it's trying to run it for language keywords like `defvar` and `progn` as well for my Lisp files. Do you think I missed something?

Comment: I am unable to duplicate the results you are seeing.  I open Emacs 26 on OSX without any user-configuration and evaluate the following snippet:  `(progn (require 'flyspell)
  (setq ispell-program-name "/absolute/path/to/the/executable/of/aspell") (find-library "flyspell") (flyspell-prog-mode))`  Then, I use `isearch` by typing `C-s` and then enter the word `defvar` and am transported to the first occurrence which is just before `flyspell-mode-map`, and then I press `RET` to exit `ispell` and leave the cursor right where it is.  When I place the cursor anywhere on the word `defvar`, no error.

Comment: I have the same result (i.e., no spelling error detected) when I use the following snippet in a `.emacs` file *without* any additional user-configuration:  `(require 'flyspell) (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode) (setq ispell-program-name "/absolute/path/to/the/executable/of/aspell") (add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (with-current-buffer (find-library "flyspell") (re-search-forward "defvar" nil t))))`  If there are other buffers that have focus, then switch to the `flyspell.el` buffer and maneuver the cursor over the word `defvar` -- I see no misspelling indicated.